# Error message object type

Tags: object, types, configuration, system, internal

I want to launch a program but it automatically shuts down with the following error message:

> Object Type System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigurationManagerInternal cannot be converted to type System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigSystem

I suppose this is C# .Net programming? How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like a bug, but without seeing the code it's hard to know how anyone would really be able to fix it. Also if it's not your code and you don't have the ability to re-compile it, there's probably not a lot you can do. I would contact the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, ADyson. I contacted the vendor "Wondershare Dr.Fone", they quickly responded to use another computer. The problem is that I don't have another computer, that's why I ask you as programming experts. Have you guys seen this specific error message window popping up before?

Comment: No, not _exactly_. It sounds like in their code they are trying to convert an object from one data type to another, and it didn't work for some reason. But like I said, no-one can actually verify that or fix it unless they have the program code and can alter it and make a new version. I'm not clear on what you would like anyone on this site to do about it?

Comment: I thought maybe you guys could help since I assume the problem has to do with my computer because the same program is supposed to work on other computers.

Comment: well since we know precisely nothing about your computer, and realistically have no way to examine the specifics of it, then no, sorry we can't compare it with any other computer. We also don't know what the system requirements of the software are, so there's no way to know whether your machine meets them or not. Also you say "supposed to"...do you know if it actually works on any other computers? If you don't know that for sure then you can't prove it's your machine which is the problem.

Comment: Since this appears to be an issue with some installed software, rather than a code-writing question, then if you can provide sufficient detail about the software and about your machine, you _might_ get a better response on https://superuser.com/